# Find a free X11 display number

Tags: x11

I have some unit tests that need an X11 display so I plan to start Xvfb before running them, but to start Xvfb I will need a free display number to connect it to. My best guess is to see what's free in `/tmp/.X11-unix` but I'm not sure how to handle the race if many tests try to start simultaneously.

sshd must do this, does anyone know how?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With full credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12169545/946850) to the related question [How high do X11 display numbers go?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12153552/946850):

Recent X servers as of version 1.13 (`Xvfb`, too) support the `-displayfd <fd>` command line option: It will make the X server choose the display itself and write the display number back to the file descriptor `<fd>`. It's a bit convoluted, but this would be a safe and race-condition-free way to ask `Xvfb` to use any free display. A `bash` example:

```
exec 6>display.log
Xvfb -displayfd 6
# The display number of the new Xvfb instance has been written to display.log 
# Kill Xvfb
exec 6>&-
```

Comment: Just a note: In Debian `Xvfb` v1.14 is available in [`jessie`](http://packages.debian.org/search?suite=jessie&searchon=names&keywords=xvfb), that means that in average distro should be quite recent (2nd half 2013 or later).

Answer (score 12):

Why not exploit the fact that every X11 server puts a "Lock" file into /tmp?

This is called /tmp/.Xn-lock where "n" is the Display id.  (Also note the leading . in the filename).

This is the mechanism that Xserver itself uses to check for duplication, and it appears to be consistent on all *nix platforms I have tried (HP-UX, Linux, ...)

So you could adapt your script thus (forgive me for syntax errors, I'm nore accustomed to C shell than Bourne/Korn shell scripting)

```
DISPLAY_NUM=0

do

  if ( -e /tmp/.X$DISPLAY_NUM-lock ) then

     let DISPLAY_NUM=$DISPLAY_NUM+1

  else

     Xvfb :$DISPLAY_NUM -screen 0 1280x1024x24 -ac   (or whatever args take your fancy)

  fi

done
```

Comment: Part of the question was how to avoid races. Your code will also fail eventually if run simultaneously.

Comment: You can help avoid races with additional custom lock - for example to put all of this inside another flock. That worked for me (better, than the actual accepted answer).

Comment: I have added a new answer below that works for me

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68128883/101152

Answer (score 5):

There's no point in trying to find a free display number.  As you have guessed, between the time you find a free one and the time Xvfb starts, another X server might have taken the port you thought was free.  So, better to just try to launch Xvfb, handle the failure if the port is taken, and then retry at the next port until you succeed or run out of ports to try.

```
#!/bin/bash
DISPLAY_NUM=0
unset TEST_HAS_RUN
until [ $TEST_HAS_RUN ] || (( $DISPLAY_NUM > 10 ))
do
 Xvfb :$DISPLAY_NUM &
 jobs
 sleep 2  # assumption here is that Xvfb will exit quickly if it can't launch
 if jobs | grep Xvfb
 then  
   echo launching test on :$DISPLAY_NUM
   xterm -display :$DISPLAY_NUM
   TEST_HAS_RUN=1
   kill %-
 else   
   let DISPLAY_NUM=$DISPLAY_NUM+1
 fi
done
```

Comment: If `xterm` launches successfully, won't it block your script until the user exits it manually? Otherwise it looks like `TEST_HAS_RUN` never gets set, and the loop never quits. In fact, it looks like  your test _passes_ if `xterm` fails to launch. Am I missing something?

Comment: Technically, if Xvfb fails and then within your 2-second sleep another X server takes the port, your test would pass on the wrong server (particularly if your script has another Xvfb in the background to satisfy `jobs | grep Xvfb` ). It would be better to launch Xvfb with a **unique** fbdir (e.g. `-fbdir /var/tmp/$0.$$.$RANDOM`), and then check for the file `Xvfb_screen0` within that directory.

Comment: @jrodatus This answer assumes "xterm" is the test, so it's correct for the display to close after that. And another instance racing against this wouldn't find the wrong server because "jobs" reports only children of this shell. krlmlr's answer is now better, though.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a bit off-topic, but if you use `xvfb-run` to start your Xserver-needing command, then just running

```
# xvfb-run -a your command
```

does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Based in the answer of @karunski.

Using Xvfb to probe the displays, and lsof to check if are unix sockets in the Xvfb process, is more effective, notice the `sleep 0.5`, can be variable depends on the machine.

```
#!/bin/bash
DISPLAY=0

until [ $DISPLAY_NUM > 10 ]; do
        echo -n "Looking for display on $DISPLAY..."
        Xvfb :$DISPLAY > /dev/null 2>&1 &
        pid=$!
        sleep 0.5
        lsof -a -U -p $pid  > /dev/null 2>&1    

        notfound="$?"
        kill $pid > /dev/null 2>&1

        wait $pid

        [ "$notfound" == "0" ] && echo "found" && break

        echo "fail"
        let DISPLAY=DISPLAY+1
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (note - uses bash)

```sh
exec {lock_fd}>/var/lock/xlockfile || exit 1
flock "$lock_fd" || { echo "ERROR: flock() failed." >&2; exit 1; }

DISPLAY_NUM=1
until [[ $xvfb ]]; do
  if [[ -e /tmp/.X$DISPLAY_NUM-lock ]]; then
    let DISPLAY_NUM=$DISPLAY_NUM+1
  else
    Xvfb :$DISPLAY_NUM -ac -screen 0 $XVFB_WHD -nolisten tcp &
    xvfb=$!
  fi
done

flock -u "$lock_fd"
```

Note that the outwards lock works only when all scripts that run the xvfb command use it, otherwise you get race conditions again