# Python subprocess.Popen pipe custom fd

Tags: python, subprocess

I currently have this code that pipe stdout or stderr following the context:

```
def execteInstruction(cmd, outputNumber):
  do_stdout = DEVNULL
  do_stderr = DEVNULL
  if outputNumber != 2:
    do_stdout = subprocess.PIPE
  else:
    do_stderr = subprocess.PIPE
  return subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stderr=do_stderr, stdout=do_stdout)
```

And then I read the result with `communicate()`. This works perfectly well except that I need to read a custom fd because I'm using subprocess to run a command that output on the file descriptor 26.

I have seen code that write to another fd than stdout or stderr, but none that read from a custom fd. 
So how can I pipe a custom fd from subprocess.Popen ?

Comment: I do not get what you want to do: Do you want to access the fd of stdout/stderr directly? or do you need to access a new fd, created by the child process? If so, what type of cmd are you running and can you provide the new fd to the cmd? And are you running on a specific plateform? `subprocess` behave differently on windows/unix...

Answer (score 2):

Since I needed an answer to this, here's a much belated answer for others:

To implement [a similar use of additional fds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18166600/435253) in Python, I came up with this code:

```py
import os, subprocess

read_pipe, write_pipe = os.pipe()
xproc = subprocess.Popen(['Xephyr', '-displayfd', str(write_pipe)],
                         pass_fds=[write_pipe])

display = os.read(read_pipe, 128).strip()
```

I think `os.dup2(write_pipe, 26)` before the `Popen` constructor combined with `pass_fds=[26]` would do that last step of getting you a specific fd number, rather than just whatever `os.pipe` chose, but I haven't tested it.

If nothing else, it should be possible to redirect fd 26 to whatever `write_pipe` turns out to be if you use `subprocess.Popen` to call a shell-script wrapper which  runs `exec 26>$WHATEVER` before calling the actual target command.